# Laravel update specific data from model where it doesn't have array of ids

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to update all model data except some from an array of ids, how is this kind of thing possible with eloquent?

What i'm doing:

Creating or updating events and setting availability to 0 also gatherings the ids in a foreach loop for each event

```
$rv = CalendarSchedule::updateOrCreate([
    'date_start' => $import['start']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'date_end' => $import['end']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'operator_id' => $operator->id
],[
    'location_id' => $operator->place_id, 
    'available' => 0,
    'block' => 1
]);
array_push($ids, $rv->id);
```

Now when the foreach loop ends i want to update all the CalendarSchedule data except those in the ids array and set `available => 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using made it work.

```
    DB::table('calendar_schedules')->whereNotIn('id', $ids)->update([
        'available' => 1
    ]);
```